# Need assistance loading SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I get a generic error when loading SSRS or trying to go into Connections. I have restarted servers and services. Any ideas? I am a novice, so any help would be greatly appreciated. I am not sure what the error means, as there is no context.

Restarted servers and services.

Comment: What do you mean by "loading"? You mean you can't get the service to start or problems connection to the SSRS instance, or you can't access the web portal?
**EDIT your question** and explain what is working and what is not, explain at exactly what point you have a problem, your question is too vague at the moment.